# Excel VBA auto update custom formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet and want to have a custom formula that will count the numbers of cells with a specific colour.

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As range, criteria As range) As Long
    Dim datax As range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

I have used the following code and it works but when I change a cell colour it doesn't automatically update the result of the formula.

On other questions I was advised that I need to add the

```
Application.Volatile
```

command inside the function. This doesn't work for me.

Has anyone any solution or is it possible if the cell colour is changed and not the contents to automatically show an updated total.

Comment: Changing a cell's format (colour or other) is insufficient to mark the cell as 'dirty'. A volatile UDF will recalculate on every calculation cycle but you have to have something occur (typically a value change anywhere in the workbook) that triggers it.

Comment: Thanks for that, if I have a question regarding that solution that won't work for me can I ask it here or on the link above?

Comment: Your asking how to make something work that was never designed to work (e.g. changing a cell's color triggering an event). If you can formulate your new line of inquiry together into a comprehensive question then start as new question (as advised to in the blurb above). Posting a comment into the other answer is unlikely to garner a response but I believe that the thread does answer every point you've brought up in this question.